# Solid reference for limit superior and inferior

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for a good reference which introduces the concepts of limit superior and inferior either online or in a book. The materials I have searched for online have not really been helpful.

Comment: You might want to include in your question a summary and/or list of the materials you have "searched for online" that "have not really been helpful" and also a more detailed description of what counts, for you, as a "good reference which introduces...".  As written, this question will be hard to answer "correctly."  We can't know what you find helpful, nor what you've already reviewed and did not find helpful, etc.

Comment: Meanwhile, please peruse [limit superior and limit inferior reference request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133556/limit-superior-and-inferior-reference-request?rq=1).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior is pretty good.